# generate java script file from template

Tags: javascript, jquery, code-generation

I want to generate java script templates for example I will give the varible and the params and it generate the function,something simliar to t4template in c#.

```
click:function(test){

var a = "test";


};
```

which tool should I use,I want some open source and when I google it didnt find anthing helpful,
please assist.
I want to use some open source which easy to use.
example will be very helpful

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish. What are you templating? How do you intend to specify the functionality of the javascript code? 

Please post more relevant code. The snippet you posted is barely valid javascript (assuming it's a property of an object that I can't see the rest of?).

Comment: @RaphaelSerota-Thanks Im not sure what to add here more,Im acatully want to generate java script file like in .net its done with  T4 template http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx ,in .net you know that if you want to generate code via template you use T4.does it answer your question?